# How to block the read system call

Tags: c, linux, io

I don't understand how read() system blocks. I have created an empty file and trying to read using the read() system call. It returns 0.

```
fd = open("Demo.txt",O_RDONLY);
n = read(fd,&ch,10); // returns 0
```

I am expecting read() to block indefinitely as there is no data in the file. Does read() consider EOF to be valid data and return immediately? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: If it didn't return at EOF, how would you know when you're done reading? All programs that read from files would hang forever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, EOF will cause read() to return immediately, not block. When you reach EOF read() doesn't wait for more data to be written to the file; it returns 0 bytes immediately. Blocking does not come into play when reading from on-disk files, aside from the usually imperceptible delay when data on disk is read into memory.

It's more relevant when working with TTYs, sockets, and pipes. For instance, reading from stdin when stdin is connected to the terminal will block until the user types something. Reading from a socket will block if we haven't received data from the other side. Reading from a pipe will block until the program on the other side of the pipe writes something.

Comment: But they don't block when you reach EOF, either.

Comment: Does it block when reading from TTYs? If so, till when? Till at least some bytes are available? Or till newline character is encountered?

Comment: read from a tty will block until some bytes are available or until VEOF tty char is entered (normally ctrl-D)

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is correct.  `read()` would block only when reading from a pipe or network socket that was connected.

Comment: No, it will block for reads on files too, if there is no data available until the data has been fetched from disk. However, when the end of file is reached, there is no need to wait, since the file contains no more data! The filesystem knows how long the files is [at the time of checking - if someone writes to the file a nanosecond later, it will be different!]

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read):

> read() attempts to read up to count bytes from file descriptor fd into the buffer starting at buf.

At no point does `read` block on a regular file, should the regular file be empty, a return of 0 (as you've seen) is expected meaning 0 bytes were read from the file.. Filetypes (such as FIFO/pipe) support blocking behavior.