# In the case of name pipe open system is a blocking call or read and write?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I have confusion about open,read and write system call in the implementation of name pipe about blocking and non blocking. I am getting confused which is blocking the process.open,read  or write.

1.read.c sample code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
main()
{
        int ret=0;
        int fd=-1;
        char buf[BUFSIZ]={0};
        fd=open("fifo",O_RDONLY);
        if(fd<0)
        {
                printf("\n mkfifo:%s",strerror(errno));
                return;
        }
        printf("\nFile has open successfully");
        while((ret=read(fd,buf,sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0])))>0)
        {
                printf("\n%s",buf);
                memset(buf,0,sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0]));
        }
        exit(0);
}
```

2.write.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
main()
{
        int ret=-2;
        int fd=-1;
        char buf[BUFSIZ]={0};
        fd=open("fifo",O_WRONLY);
        if(fd<0)
        {
                printf("\n mkfifo:%s",strerror(errno));
                return;
        }
        printf("\nFile has open successfully");
                printf("Enter Message:");
                fgets(buf,sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0]),stdin);
        ret=write(fd,buf,sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0]));
        memset(buf,0,sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0]));
        exit(0);
}
```

I have gone through this link also

[How to block the read system call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713800/how-to-block-the-read-system-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `O_NDELAY` or `O_NONBLOCK` is not specified, an open on a FIFO blocks until both a reader and a writer are present.

But for exemple if you change your code to: (in write.c)

```
  if ((fd=open("fifo", O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK)) < 0)
    {
      perror("open");
      return;
    }
```

It's going to be nonblocking

[more info](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-4855/pipe6-34003.html)

Comment: We should not open pipe or fifo in O_RDWR mode.Because the both are unidirectional in nature .So if we open it in O_RDWR mode then the behaviour will be undefined.Yes you are right open system call is going to block the process .In that case we should have both reader and writer code.Means if you have open a fifo in O_RDONLy then we have to open the file O_WRONLY.